# Java で 年月日 などから Date をインスタンス化する

Tags: java, kotlin

JST　の　「年　月　日　時　分　秒　ミリ秒」　からDateをインスタンス化したいです。
それは↓のコードで完璧に動作します。

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH mm ss SSS z");
format.parse(new StringBuilder()
.append(year).append(' ')
.append(month).append(' ')
.append(day).append(' ')
.append(hour).append(' ')
.append(minute).append(' ')
.append(second).append(' ')
.append(milli).append(" JST").toString());
```

ですが、このコードは非効率だと思います。
なぜなら、日付情報などはフォーマットで保持しておらず、最初から整数として持っているからです。
このコードだと
年月日などの整数　→　フォーマット　→　フォーマット解析　→　Date
という処理になってしまいます。

もっと効率よくDateをインスタンス化する方法を探しています。

```
Calendar cl = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("JST"));
cl.set(uear, month-1, day, hour, minute, second);
cl.getTime();
```

このCalendarを使用するコードは動作する端末のディフォルトタイムゾーンにより思うように動作しません。
私は事前にJSTをCalendarにセットすれば`set`メソッドで指定する数値はJSTのものでいいと思っていましたがそうではないみたいで

例えば

***2020/06/27 00:54:01 557***

という日付をCalendarでDateに変換したとき、
***【UTC端末で実行したら】***
Fri Jun 26 15:54:01 UTC 2020
1593186841557
このタイムスタンプを日本時間に変換すると「2020/06/27 00:54:01」なので正常

***【JST端末で実行したら】***
Sat Jun 27 09:54:01 GMT+09:00 2020
1593219241766
このタイムスタンプを日本時間に変換すると「2020/06/27 09:54:01」となりタイムゾーン関連で期待通りの数値になりませんでした。

どのような方法がありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OffsetDateTime.of()`で`OffsetDateTime`オブジェクトを生成した後、`Date`へ変換することができます。

```java
// 2020/06/27 00:54:01 557 (JST)
// 注: 第7引数はミリ秒でなくナノ秒
final OffsetDateTime datetime = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 6, 27, 0, 54, 1, 557_000_000, ZoneOffset.ofHours(9));
// final ZonedDateTime datetime = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 6, 27, 0, 54, 1, 557_000_000, ZoneId.of("JST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS));
final Date date = Date.from(datetime.toInstant());
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。提示いただいたコードで私の思うように動作できました！